# Is there a way to retrieve information about new app builds from TestFlight?

Tags: testflight

I am using TestFlight to distribute test versions of my app to a private group of people. As I am making a lot of updates these days I wonder if some of my testers will get sick of the large amount of update emails they receive.

So I thought it would be a better approach to let the app check for updates when started and than showing a small notification that there is a new version out and to only notify the testers about important updates by mail.

So my question is: Is there a way to retrieve information about new builds by RSS or some other channel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TestFlight iOS SDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/ios/doc/2.1.3/) already supports this for beta versions if you have the SDK integrated into your app:

> Beta In App Updates
>
> If a user is using a beta version of your app, you are setting the
>   UDID, a new beta version is available, and that user has permission to
>   install it; an in app popup will ask them if they would like to
>   install the update. If they tap "Install", the new version is
>   installed from inside the app.
>
> NB: For this to work, you must increment your build version before
>   uploading. Otherwise the new and old builds will have the same version
>   number and we won't know if the user needs to update or is already
>   using the new version.
>
> To turn this off set this option before calling takeOff:
>
> `[TestFlight setOptions:@{ TFOptionDisableInAppUpdates : @YES }];`

Comment: Thank you, I just overlooked That. Will try it.